# Input 20 elements as one

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to automate an input by inserting 20 elements at a time. The textarea that I need to use won't let me use ("A2:A21") as a range. I need to  create a variable somehow to stock 20 elements at a time, but I also have a second problem, if I have let's say a total of 65 elements, how can I create the variable so when it finishes all the 20 elem groups to create a 5 group?

```
    Sub test()
Set thisWbs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

i = i
x = i + 19
ie.Visible = True

Set Rng = thisWbs.Range("A2:A" & x)



my_url = "index.html"
ie.navigate my_url
While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Focus
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Click


ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).Focus
ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).Click
ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).innerText = Range("A2" & x)
i = i + 1
Next x
End Sub
```

I will attach here a code that works:

```
Sub test()
    Set thisWbs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True

    my_url = "index.html"
    ie.navigate my_url
    While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Focus
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Click

    ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).Focus
    ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).Click
    ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).innerText = Range("A1")
    End Sub
```

Using the code up-mentioned it populates the textarea with the value from A1, but I want it to populate it with the values from A1 to A19 and then with A20 to A39 and A40 to A45 (so with 20 items when it's possible and when not with the remaining items).

[image: 1st bulk]

[image: 2nd bulk]

[image: 3rd bulk]

[image: 4th bulk]

All my data is in column A as it follows: A2=1, A3=2, A4=3...A64=63, A65=64.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what exactly you want to do. Also your `Next x` has no `For`. What is the purpose of `i = i`? That doesn't make any sense at this point `i` is `0` and it will stay `0`. Please improve your question, tell what is wrong with your code and give a good example of what you want to achieve. Reading [mvce] could help to improve your question.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
Const WINDOW_SIZE As Long = 20

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'your worksheet name

Dim LastRow As Long 'find last data row in column A
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 2 To LastRow Step WINDOW_SIZE 'pick window sizes of 20 rows
    Dim ConcatValues As String
    ConcatValues = vbNullString 'initialize

    'concatenate the 20 values to one
    Dim sRow As Long
    For sRow = iRow To WorksheetFunction.Min(iRow + WINDOW_SIZE - 1, LastRow)
        ConcatValues = ConcatValues & ws.Range("A" & sRow).Value & vbCrLf
    Next sRow

    'put that concatenated value in your element
    ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).innerText = ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).innerText & ConcatValues & vbCrLf
    Debug.Print ConcatValues & vbCrLf 'this can be removed in productive code later
    'this has to be adjusted by your needs
Next iRow
```

Comment: It works and not, it concatenates only the last 4 elements (so exclude the sets of 20), but I don't need the concatenated, I need them on top of each other.

Comment: @Psko Please edit your original question and add some example source data and the desired result that sould be inserted in `.innerText`. Otherwise it is unclear what you mean. Screenshots might help too. • Note that this code has to be adjusted too your needs where I commented and then it will work as desired.  Checkout my edit

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Same idea like Pᴇʜ

You can do it with a loop

```
Sub test()

Dim thisWbs As Worksheet
Dim ie As Object
Dim my_url As String
Dim upToTwenty As String
Dim upToTwentyCounter As Long
Dim currentRow As Long

  Set thisWbs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  currentRow = 2
  my_url = "index.html"

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate my_url
  While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

  'What happens after each click?
  'It is possible that a small pause is necessary to
  'execute the action behind a click before continuing
  ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Click
  ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).Click

  'Combine up to 20 values from column A
  'If a separator is required, it must be inserted
  Do While thisWbs.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value <> "" Or upToTwentyCounter > 20
    upToTwenty = upToTwenty & thisWbs.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
    upToTwentyCounter = upToTwentyCounter + 1
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Loop

  ie.document.getElementsByName("fnsku")(1).innerText = upToTwenty

  'Reset variables
  upToTwenty = ""
  upToTwentyCounter = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: application-defined or object-defined error on Do While thisWbs.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value <> "" Or upToTwentyCounter > 20

Comment: Because `currentRow` was not initialized it is `0` and a row `0` does not exist. Initialize the `currentRow` with `currentRow = 2` before running the loop.

Comment: @Psko Yeah, I forgot to initialize it. Just insert at the top like Pᴇʜ wrote.

Comment: PeH's method works but it seems that this one still doesn't even after initializing it.

Comment: @Psko I just wanted to show you how to combine the values in your code. If you can work with the solution from Pᴇʜ, that's great :-)